# Downsides of making a git repo in the root

Tags: python, git, unix

I am currently working on a git repo located in

```
/home/user/bin/git/my-project
```

so i am saving the project as I work on it. But i have an issue, my project depends on python libraries, crontab configuration, bashrc/.profile variables and if i need to transfer all of this on another linux system I was wondering if it was possible to host the whole directory right from root? like:

```
git/home/user/bin/git/my-project
```

so that when i want to retrieve the exact same copy and update the second machine, it works exactly like the first? Is it possible? are there any downsides?

thanks in advance for your help

EDIT: Thanks for your answers, by root I meant the directory which does not have a parent directory. On my raspberry pi I probably meant the place where you find (etc, var, usr, boot, dev...). So how would you proceed, if you wanted to (for example) have another RPI with the exact same function without having to duplicate what's in the SD card? and everyone working on a different system have the exact same functionnality, up to date?
Thanks!

Comment: Your dependencies are fetched and/or generated as part of your build/installation process. They are not part of the project itself, at least as far as Git is concerned.

Comment: Projects or any other user data should not go into `bin` directories. They are for executable and `$HOME/bin` might even be added to the `PATH`.

Comment: For the dependencies, you typically have a `requirements.txt`. You can't simply copy everything, e.g. if one machine is 32 bit and the other is 64 bit.

Comment: (That is, you are confusing Git with `tar`.)

Comment: Your definition of "root" seems to be something quite different than what is commonly meant by this word (i.e. the directory which does not have a parent directory). Perhaps you could rephrase this question - please [edit] to clarify what you actually mean.

Comment: Disaster on many levels. Not useful.

Comment: When I had a git repo at `/`, some programs wouldn't work (`eclipse` or other), because in a project they tested if they are inside a git repo and they run `git status` to check the files, which ended up git scanning the whole hard drive each time application opens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Downsides of making a git repo in the root (ie. in `/`)

Some IDE applications work horribly slow, because they "autodetect" if they are inside a git repo and then try to run `git status` to check for changes. This ends up indexing the whole filesystem. I remember a problem with eclipse and NetBeans (I think NetBeans didn't start at all, because it tried to open read-write some git files, and they were owned by root, but I'm not sure).

> how would you proceed, if you wanted to (for example) have another RPI with the exact same function without having to duplicate what's in the SD card?

Create a package for the distribution installed on the platform. Create a publicly available repository with that package. Add that repository to the native package manager of that platform and install it like a normal package.

Package manager is **the way** of distributing stuff to systems. Package managers have dependency resolution, easy-updates, pre-/post-install scripts and hooks, all the functionality you need to distribute programs. And package managers have great support of removing files and updates.

> my project depends on python libraries

So install them, via `pip` `pyenv` or the best via the package manager available on the system, the system administrators choice. Or request the user to setup a `venv` after installing your application.

> , crontab configuration

(Side note: see `systemd` timers).

> , bashrc/.profile variables

If your library depends on my home customization, you have zero chances of installing it on any of my systems. There is zero need to touch home directory stuff if you want to distribute a library to systems. Applications have `/etc` for configuration, and most distributions have `/etc/profile.d/` as the standard directory for drop-in shell configuration. Please research linux directory structure, see Filesystem Hierarchy Specification and XDG specifications.

Still, requesting users to do manual configuration after installing a package is normal. Some applications to work need environmental variables.

If you want to propagate change to different computers and manage that change, then use ansible, puppet, chef and such automation tools.

Comment: Hey, so to clarify a bit, every configuration I do in the home directory (.profile/.bashrc) is not useful? They should always go in etc/ directory? Someone said bin was for executables, is there a standard to where i should place my project? Thanks for the tip on package manager though, i will look into it!

Comment: `every configuration I do in the home directory (.profile/.bashrc) is not useful?` I do not understand - in terms of "useful" surely they are. Home directory if for __me__ to change, however I want. I will oppose any tool editing my bash files automatically on installation. `is there a standard to where i should place my project?` As mentioned FHS and XDG. But each distribution has it's own directory structure. If you want to have a "project" as a whole, then `/opt`.